# Oracle Format Float Numbers 11g

Tags: oracle, casting, floating-point, type-conversion

I want to format

```
if integer, then integer.00

if float, then float.xx (2 digits of precision)
```

I have a division operation whose value may result in an integer or float. I want to store the result with 2 digits of precision. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you talking about storing data?  Or displaying data?  From a data storage standpoint, you cannot store something like 1.00-- that will simply be stored as 1.  You can, of course, control how the value is displayed to the user and display the string `1.00`.  Similarly, you can round (or trunc) a real number to two decimal digits before storing it or you can store the value with full precision and simply display two digits of precision to the user.

Comment: @JustinCave It is about displaying data.

Comment: @Bob: Second to last sentence "I want to **store** the result with 2 digits of precision". Though I think this is possible. See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the round operator or simply format it if it really is output only.

```
round  ( value/divisor , 2)
to_char( value/divisor ,'99,999,999,990.99')
```

Please remark the `0` before the decimal point. This makes a value below 1 look more pretty with a leading zero. eg. `0.55` instead of `.55`.

[Example SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d4c1b/1)

```
create table test (dividend       number, 
                   divisor        number, 
                   result         number,
                   result_rounded number);

insert into test values (100,10,null,null);
insert into test values (9,5,null,null);
insert into test values (10,15,null,null);

update test set  result         = dividend / divisor
                ,result_rounded = round(dividend/divisor,2); 

select * from test;
```

Result:

```
    DIVIDEND   DIVISOR     RESULT           RESULT_ROUNDED
    100        10          10               10
    9          5           1.8              1.8
    10         15          0.666666666667   0.67
```

But at the end when you try to output this then the formatting comes into play and the rounding does not make much difference.

[Example SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d4c1b/3)

```
select to_char(result,'99,999,999,990.99'),
       to_char(result_rounded,'99,999,999,990.99') 
from test;
```

Result

```
10.00    10.00
1.80     1.80
0.67     0.67
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(1,'99,999,999,999.99') FROM DUAL;  -- THIS GIVES 1.OO

SELECT TO_CHAR(1.3,'99,999,999,999.99') FROM DUAL;  -- THIS GIVES 1.30
```

The repeated `99999` is just for BILLION formatting. For thousands, it should be `999,999.99`